# Geocoding with Google Maps and Mapstraction - static address in HTML code will not work

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-geocoder

I am new to setting up geocoding on a Google Map Page and I am using examples from the book Map Scripting 101. I am attempting to bring up a static address that is geocoded on a Google Map.  I tried to transfer the code to my own html page and it will not work.  I substituted my Google API key, and the paths to my mapstraction directory is correct. I am definitely in the correct website to use my code as I have no problems with my Google API working with other maps.  The problem is just the geocoding of a static address in the html code.

I think I have set up all the proper services when I obtained my Google API.  However I am not clear if there is a special API service that is needed for geocoding in addition to making standard maps.

Here is the HTML code that I cannot get to work.  All that shows up is a shell with no map inside and no geocoded point.    I obtained this code from the samples in the book and on the accompanying website for the book.

```
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyDYqIvje6tt-`enter code here`g4NnWOLAVqwBWCcMuI5rvM&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/mxn.js?(google)"></script>
    <script src="js/mxn.google.geocoder.js"></script>
    <style>
    div#mymap {
        width: 400px;
        height: 350px;
    }
    div#clicks {
        width: 400px;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mapstraction;
    var mks = [];
    function create_map() {
        mapstraction = new mxn.Mapstraction('mymap', 'google');
        mapstraction.addSmallControls();
        mapstraction.setMapType(mxn.Mapstraction.PHYSICAL);
        mapstraction.setCenterAndZoom(defaultcenter, 15);

        geocoder = new MapstractionGeocoder(add_point, 'google');
        var address = {
          street: "38 Ringold Street",
          locality: "San Francisco",
          region: "CA",
          country: "US"
        };

        //OR:
        //var address = {
        //  address: "38 Ringold St, San Francisco, CA"
        //};

        geocoder.geocode(address);
    }
    function add_point(loc) {
        var mk = new mxn.Marker(loc.point);

        mk.setInfoBubble(loc.address);
        mapstraction.addMarker(mk);
        mk.openBubble();
        mapstraction.autoCenterAndZoom();
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="create_map()">
    <div id="mymap"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```